# NSToolBar with two customize buttons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

i am a beginner in mac development. i am developing an application with Toolbar. i just want to add Two customized Button in the tool bar.

The ToolBar will be looking like this. i have tried this using XIB, but i did not get this thing,.,.[image: THIS]

any ideas about this,.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to **validate** each toolbar item that is not default.

---

Long answer:

1. First you need to connect *actions* of `NSToolbarItem` to a `IBAction` in your code.
2. Then you have two option:

   - Let the automatic validator do his job by simply checking if there is valid target/action pair.
   - **Validate** each toolbar item yourself. You can check here if there is anything to *Copy/Paste*

Exemple of validation:

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id < NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem >)theMenuItem {
    BOOL enable = NO;

    if ([theMenuItem action] == @selector(myCopy:)) {
        if (isThereSomethingToCopy)
            enable = YES;
    }
    else if ([theMenuItem action] == @selector(myPaste:)) {
        if ( (isThereSomethingToPaste) && (thereIsValidPasteTarget) )
            enable = YES;
    }
    return enable;
}
```